# Optimize linq statement

Tags: c#, linq

I have the linq statement below. How can I solve this without the loop. It is a tag system and I only want those exercises that have the tags with the ids in "myints"

```
int[] myints = {1,2};
  foreach (int tagid_temp in myints)
  {
    ExerciseByTagId = 
        (from exercise in context.ExerciseSet
         where context.ItemsTagsSet
               .Where(a => a.TagsId == tagid_temp)
               .Select(a => a.ExerciseId).Contains(exercise.Id)
      select exercise);
  }
```

Comment: Looks like you are just overwriting `ExerciseByTagId` in every iteration in the loop. So it will always be assigned the value from the last iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing a little based on your query, but something like this?

(**EDIT** - realized my first example would return duplicate exercises if multiple matching tags were found)

<strike>int[] myints = {1,2};</strike>

```
ExerciseByTagId = 
    context.ExerciseSet
           .Where(e => context.ItemsTags
                              .Any(t=> t.ExerciseId == e.Id 
                                         && myints.Contains(t.TagsId)  
                 );
```

To get the items where ALL of the related items are in the list:

```
int[] myints = new int[] {1,2};

var ExerciseByTagId = 
    context.ExerciseSet
    .Where(
        e => context.ItemsTags
                    .Where(t=> t.ExerciseId == e.Id) 
                    .All(t => myints.Contains(t.TagsId))  
        );
```

Comment: Maybe I am a bit bad to explain but I only want the exercises that have ALL the tags matching "myints". The for loop gives me this but in a bad way?

Answer (score 0):

`Contains()`is pretty close to what you need, so use your own `ContainsAll()` function:

```
public static bool ContainsAll<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, params T[] matches)
{
    return matches.All(value => sequence.Contains(value));
}
```

Comment: That would push the filter to the client rather than in the database because you are using IEnumerable rather than IQueryable.

Comment: But there is no SQL equivalent to a `ContainsAll` function.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this on a rather similar db structure, and it produces a single SQL statement:

```
var selected = new [] {1,2};

var ex = from ts in context.ItemsTagsSet
         where selected.Contains(ts.TagsId)
         group ts by ts.ExerciseId into g select new
         {
            ExerciseId = g.Key,
            Count      = g.Count()
         } into x
         where x.Count == selected.Length
         join e in context.ExerciseSet on e.ExerciseId equals x.ExerciseId 
         select e;
```